# Evitar que nl2br() introduzca más de un salto de linea

Tags: php

Me estoy encontrando con un problema. Uso la función de `PHP` `nl2br()` para que al escribir un artículo, los saltos de linea me los introduzca en la base de datos con un `<br>`. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema viene cuando quiero editar dicho artículo. Cargo la información del artículo, y si lo vuelvo a guardar lo haya modificado o no, me vuelve a incluir otro `<br>`, y así sucesivamente.

¿ Hay alguna forma de limitar esto?

Comment: Tal vez sea mejor usar `nl2br()` solo al mostrar el artículo al visitante, no al guardarlo en bd, otra posible solución sería cambiar los `br` por `\n` antes de editar el artículo.

Comment: De momento la única solución que he encontrado es que al editar el artículo, eliminar las etiquetas `<br>`, pero esperaba que hubieses alguna forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Como te indican en los comentarios, tendrías dos opciones:

1. Aplicar `nl2br` sólo cuando vayas a mostrar el artículo a los visitantes. Se este modo no tienes que estar cambiando `br` por `\n` (y viceversa) continuamente mientras editas.
2. Crear tu propia función `br2nl`. En la página de la [documentación de `nl2br` se sugiere una posible implementación de `br2nl`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php#86678) que podría servirte, y que tendrías que aplicar al artículo antes de editarlo:

   ```
   function br2nl($string)
   {
       return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
   }
   ```